# Self referencing with same class

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class called "ApplicationUser", this class has a property called followers which is the same type like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public string FcmToken { get; set; }
    public bool NotificationEnabled { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> Followers { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> Follows { get; set; }
}
```

and in my ApplicationDbContext in the method "OnModelCreating" is like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(s => s.Followers).WithMany().Map(m =>
        {

        });           

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

the error is in the .WithMany(), it says "Application User does not contain a definition for WithMany"

I have been seeing tutorials about self referencing and this is the way to do it using Entity Framework 6, but i have not founf the way to do it using .net core 2.2
Any help will be helpful to me. Thanks advanced.

Comment: What you have shown is the EF6 model of many-to-many relationship with implicit join entity. This is not supported yet by EF Core - you need to create explicit join entity and modify the navigation properties accordingly - see [Relationships - Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) topic in EF Core documentation.

Comment: you are right it is for EF 6

Answer (score 0):

EF Core doesn't actually support many-to-many relationships. The workaround is using an intermediate entity to join the two sides, such that there's a one to many between each side of the relationship and that intermediate class. In other words:

```
public class ApplicationUserFollower
{
    public ApplicationUser Follower { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Followee { get; set; }
}
```

Then on `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...

    public ICollection<ApplicationUserFollower> Following { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserFollower> Followers { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, in your fluent config:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(s => s.Following).WithOne(x => x.Follower);
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(s => s.Followers).WithOne(x => x.Followee);
```

Comment: I did it, but when i'm gonna update database appears this error : "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 "

Comment: That's a totally unrelated issue. You likely have your context in a class library, in which case, there's special things you need to do. The link in the error gives you all the info you need.